# What is the best way to convert vector<vector<string>> into vector<vector<double>>?

Tags: c++, algorithm, type-conversion

The below is the example.

```
vector<vector<string>> vec_str = {{"123", "2015", "18"}, {"345", "2016", "19"}, {"678", "2018", "20"}};
vector<vector<double>> vec_dou;
```

I want to convert vec_str to {{123, 2015, 18}, {345, 2016, 19}, {678, 2018, 20}}.
I try to use std::transform method, but when I use transform in for loop or while loop, it did not work well, that means it returned error code 03.

```
[Thread 11584.0x39f4 exited with code 3]
[Thread 11584.0x5218 exited with code 3]
[Inferior 1 (process 11584) exited with code 03]
```

I don't know the exact reason for error, so please don't ask me for that.. VS code only returned the above error. ;-(

What is the best way for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work well"? If you encountered an error, please include it in your question. The [`std::stod` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) should work for converting string to double.

Comment: @jtbandes okay. My intention is not asking the error, but just asking what your experiences were for converting the type of 2d vector to other vector.

Comment: please include your code as well

Comment: exit code 3 maybe means ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND 3 (0x3)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a nested `std::transform`:

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gDMpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHObxocjeWADUJvFuTgoExJisB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHAG7VRMSX13cVD157BzcJ2IoWAX1u9wY23%2BT0BYmAJEICBY4Luty8aSMu2YbAUSSYq12J3QByst1CBF2LCYoQgc32AHYyTddqzdm8HCRARyPoDgaCvvFsOzqgB9YHPAAijKsTPMZi4FXlpH2ZjVGi4AFZlaqFQAOeUmBmSlVGqxq%2BKSbVq01qswagBsOvlXAAnIbjaa5WqHQyDTbdfauP6AoGNB7JUbI/FmWyRZzPq93lzDugllF6ILhRzRWmvKTvt848SQCBToYFPxiCwIDngQA6GLAWkLePi0711x0lUlkBRAkAa1FoSUjVitbFedbJk1Vk1kogaAYJ12TC8RHMDqJpwU9LNRbjbJ5KbceYzmEuuzOCi8tAIBduh7ZvfLy6rNeBCkbmGbDG72%2BIL8u1bXt%2B2QIcR1iAhx2vW8CGnWcZwXJcVzXDczC3YE9yZK9MAIZYGG3dBSxODAICw0lGUlOYHxZJ9cPw4hCNgu9aLjKMaJjQtHzZKtdkXARUPXVBN2xHwFF2EA2ynGUDyfPiIDPehdnQSSxJYXdZJ4%2Bi2TQddnjcQFdjADhjNMwEjJJLjtMPKM5MPPTKQsw5dlcWg2LZOyIWNDgFloThNV4PwOC0UhUE4QzLGsIklhWWEKh4UgCE0XyFgHEBNQ0fROEkIKUrCzheAUEAsuSkLfNIOBYCQJYCCSddyEoNAWCSOgBi4QJ8A%2BPR%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUcqkrONZEoAd2IJgkk4Hg/ICvKJvCjgAHl13qylUCoXZVD1B0AFoHUkXZtkMYBdi4eJ6w0B7%2BI8Fq2uIVV4i4OZeDKrQFggJBmta%2BgyAoATXpBlADCMO6NCymg71iYqICifKolCBoAE8lt4Zq2EETaGFobGJqwakjHEUm8DOGo3mKibMFUap1zWUKKUwfyJtoPAonm4hMY8LB8tOPAWBxhYqAMYAFAANTwTAZs2pJGBx4bhFEcQht6%2BQlDUfLdA66HjGsax9B54rIAWVAkkcQTCtsDn3gyFwGHcTwWj0YIphKMo9BSNJbcyd2cg6/2CgYXoffah37EDroRmDvwOvaOOJkj/o4mTiZRiToZunTmZM4WBRYtWPRTkwaaKs5wLSGC0KNqO07zsuo3bvux6NGek3LBVXBCBID6Ot2F7gdiIfvqSlK5jSjKss53K6/yjaipKqfypn7KODMNaG/t37UtIN5AOdyQgA)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<vector<string>> vec_str = {{"123", "2015", "18"}, {"345", "2016", "19"}, {"678", "2018", "20"}};
    vector<vector<double>> vec_dou;

    std::transform(vec_str.begin(), vec_str.end(), std::back_inserter(vec_dou), [](const auto& strs) {
        vector<double> result;
        std::transform(strs.begin(), strs.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [](const auto& str) { return std::stod(str); });
        return result;
    });

    for (const auto& nums : vec_dou) {
        for (double d : nums) {
            cout << ' ' << d;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: A very concise and readable solution. +1 for the nested `std::transform`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way of doing it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main( )
{
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > vec_str = { {"123", "2015", "18"},
                                                        {"345", "2016", "19"},
                                                        {"678", "2018", "20"} };
    // construct vec_dou at exactly the dimensions of vec_str
    std::vector< std::vector<double> >
    vec_dou( vec_str.size( ), std::vector<double>( vec_str[0].size( ) ) );


    for ( std::size_t row = 0; row < vec_str.size( ); ++row )
    {
        for ( std::size_t col = 0; col < vec_str[0].size( ); ++col )
        {
            vec_dou[row][col] = std::stod( vec_str[row][col] ); // convert each
        }                                                       // string to double
    }

    for ( const auto& doubleNumbers : vec_dou ) // print the double numbers
    {
        for ( const double& num : doubleNumbers )
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << num;
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The output:

```
 123 2015 18
 345 2016 19
 678 2018 20
```